# How to create and export iOS framework from OSS repository's source code?

Tags: ios, xcode, twitterkit

I'm new to Xcode.
I'm using twitter-kit-ios, and I wanna use it fixing its bug.
We can download the source code from https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/releases , but I cannot build it into `TwitterKit.framework` in Xcode.

I tried opening the `TwitterKit.xcodeproj` and building it, but nothing is created.

How to create `TwitterKit.framework` from the source code?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I checked it and it builds the framework fine, it's located in `<DerivedData Folder> -> TwitterKit-xxx -> Build -> Products -> <Configuration>-<platform> -> TwitterKit.framework`

Comment: Thank you! I got the TwitterKit.framework, but I cannot build it into my app.

Comment: All thing I have to do is adding `TwitterKit.framework` directory directly into my project, link it and build app?

Comment: Added 2 pics in my question. I fetched `TwitterKit.framework` directory into my app project.

Comment: `Project Settings > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries` and `Project Settings > Build Phases > Embed Frameworks`

Comment: **Both** of `Link Binary With Libraries` and  `Embed Frameworks` is needed?